# Python numpy.diff not giving negative numbers calculating acceleration?

Tags: python, list, numpy, numbers, concave

```
import numpy as np

data = [128,64,32,16,8,4,2,1]
data = np.array(data, dtype=float)
velocity = np.diff(data)
acceleration = np.diff(velocity)

print(acceleration)
```

The above code gives me the following output:

`[32. 16.  8.  4.  2.  1.]`

These numbers should be NEGATIVE and I have no idea what's going on with numpy

Thank you!

Comment: No, the acceleration here is positive. The *velocity* is negative. So it is correct.

Comment: Oh my gosh you're right thank you

Answer (score 1):

> These numbers should be NEGATIVE and I have no idea what's going on with numpy.

This is not a problem with numpy. The *velocity* here is *negative*, but the *acceleration* is positive (since the velocity is increasing over time).